# Sharepoint 2013 OOTB way to validate a "Yes" on Form Checkbox?

Tags: validation

I have a checkbox on my form and do not want users to be able to submit the form unless it's checked.

Under my List Settings > Validation Settings I'm using the formula:

```
=[Acknowledgement]="Yes"
```

but it returns the User Message validation error message regardless if the checkbox is checked or not.

Do I just have an error in my syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with:

```
=[Acknowledgement]=TRUE
```

Or

```
=[Acknowledgement]
```

Comment: If Acknowledgement is a Boolean field you can even skip the ``=TRUE`` part, as the comparison now is either ``TRUE=TRUE`` or ``FALSE=TRUE``